# Will elementary OS run on an Intel Core 2 Duo U9300?

Tags: system-installation, hardware

I'm thinking about making a switch from Windows to elementary OS. Could you tell me whether my laptop's processor, an Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU U9300 @ 1.20GHz would be appropriate and suitable?

Answer (score 2):

Elementary OS recommended system specifications for the best experience:

- Recent Intel i3 or comparable dual-core 64-bit processor
- 4 GB of system memory (RAM)
- Solid state drive (SSD) with 15 GB of free space
- Internet access
- 1024×768 display

You could try, but in my opinion you should pick a lightweight GNU/Linux distributions(Xubuntu, Lubuntu etc.) can be better experience.

Comment: That is true, and i correct my previous answer

Comment: Hey, thank you, regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well given that I've now become better acquainted with them, I'll soon seek to make those processor upgrades for elementary OS to be installed upon my laptop in accordance with these prerequisites. Again thank you a great deal, much more and so on.